# How does MySQL evaluate Text and VarChar fields when compared to booleans?

Tags: sql, mysql

Like `select * from table where text_field;`

What would get pulled?

Comment: Did you try it? What did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `select * from atable where text_field;` , you will get the rows where text_field='1'.

Similar to `select * from atable where text_field='1';`.

I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

An error.

My best guess is that you want `select * from table where text_field is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

ceteras is right, `WHERE text_field` returns true where text_field = '1' (for some obscure reason).

However, pay attention : NULL is not equal to an empty string (NULL is not even equal to NULL !). If you want to select every row where the column text_field is not **empty**, you would have to do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(text_field) > 0;
-- or
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text_field <> '';
```

The last query can use an index if wanted, I am not so sure about the first.